# Why doesn't my recipes show up in Google Recipes search results?

Tags: google-rich-snippets

My recipes were in google recipes Gallery but suddonly desappeared from it.

I check all my recipes on: https://search.google.com/test/rich-results but shows me everything fine.

i don't know what i should to do.

Please help

my domain: https://airfryerrezepte.de/

Thanks in Advance

i wrote google forum but didn't get any satify solution.